# How to query field equals empty array?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an array field in my collection which have value with properties or empty value as "[]"

For fetching the documents having empty "[]" value in mongodb i use

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({"ArrayFieldName":{$eq:[]}})
```

This gives me result as expected. But when i try to form this query in the C# using mongodb driver i couldnt get the expected Result.

I tried,
 `filterBuilder.Eq("ArraryFieldName", "[]")` and `filterBuilder.Eq("ArraryFieldName", new ArraryClassName(){})`

Need help with C# filter builder to specify $eq:[] for arrary field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instance of `ArraryClassName` clearly won't work because it's not an array instance - it's a single object. Likewise `"[]"` won't work because it's a `string`.

You can check directly translate your CLI query to this filter:

```
Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq<BsonArray>("ArraryFieldName", new BsonArray())
```

Though if you simply want to check that the existing array is empty, you can use this filter instead:

```
Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Size("ArraryFieldName", 0)
```

P.S. I would strongly suggest using C# data models as it makes everything much easier to work with.

Also, you have called your field ArraryFieldName (notice the extra `r` at the end of Array). If you don't have existing data with this misspelled property name, you might want to correct the spelling.

Comment: This worked Filter.Eq<BsonArray>("ArraryFieldName", new BsonArray())... I tried with Model class previously, but it not giving required value "[]" instead it coming with property names with default values.... BsonArray provided required output

Comment: You can still use string property names if needed (it's not obvious but it works), but with a model you can use something like `model => model.ArrayFieldName`, if that array field exists in your model object.